# Duvida sobre content activity

Tags: android

Sempre que crio minha segunda `Activity`, é gerado dois layouts para ela. No meu caso foi o `activity_pincipal` e `content_principal`.

Por que isso ocorre?

Answer (score 1):

São os arquivos para design do seu aplicativo, o content é o conteudo que você coloca dentro do aplicativo como textviews list views etc.

Comment: E quanto ao activity_principal? Que tipo de coisas posso fazer com o ele?

Comment: activity man é o design da "pagina inicial" do seu app e o content é o conteudo